# Extracting Firmware file from Wireshark Dump

Tags: firmware, wireshark, binwalk

I updated a device over a firmware update software and sniffed the whole traffic with wireshark. There is a TCP Stream with ~30MB which I exported as raw data. The resulting file is `Zip archived data` but it has a CRC error when I try to extract it with binwalk/7zip.

I also tried to export as hex dump and make `xxd -r -p dump outfile`.

In the pcap file are many `TCP DUP ACK` and `TCP Out-Of-Order` packets. 
I wonder if the exported binary takes over these dupes or out-of-order stuff.

I also tried `chaosreader -r dump.pcap` still corrupt.

Extracting the .exe with 7zip failed also with checksum error.

Any of you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are those network packets ciphered with SSL keys or simple HTTP packets? If it was encrypted connection then you've to use Fiddler like tools to decrypt HTTPs traffic.

Comment: It's plaintext and no HTTP.
After loading the firmware to the device it sends a command like "DO_FW_UPGRADE". It looks like an own protocol on port 5056/5053.